SQL Server nonclustered unique index blank space behavior at the beginning
The issue is as follows: if I try to insert into a table that has a nonclustered unique index:
'hi'
'hi '

This will show a duplication error
'hi'
' hi'

This will not show a duplication error.
I've already tried to put some LIKE ' %' AND use REPLACE or LEFT function on the WHERE clause of the NONCLUSTERED INDEX and it didn't worked obviously.
So is there any way to pull this through? I wouldn't like to have to use a trigger to check for this every time an INSERT/UPDATE is made.

It's expected behaviour. Trailing spaces are ignored for comparison purposes in SQL, leading are not. This isn't unique to SQL Server, it's part of the more fundament SQL specifications.

Computed column like LTRIM(RTRIM(yor_varchar_column)) and unique-index on this column

"So is there any way to pull this through?" pull what through, exactly? You don't actually tell us what you expect; you just tell us the behaviour you're getting; which is expected behaviour.

You could add a check constraint on that column, to disallow leading spaces

Or if you really do need trailing spaces to be unique then create a computed column ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD YourColumnBinary AS CONVERT(varbinary(100), YourColumn, 0) then add a unique index to that instead.
